# Data to the next column skips (C)

Tags: c, data-representation

I am working on a code and I have problem representing the data into the form of row and column. The row collects data from a binary file and after 349 data are collected, it moves to the next column. However, the problem that I am encountering is that, the data I gathered skips to the 4008 data to 4008+349... so it skips datas from 350 to 4008. I need data from 350 to 350+349 to fill the next column and so on for the next columns too. However, I couldn't troubleshoot where the problem lies. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
 for (i = 0; i < DATAPERROW; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < NUMPLOTS; j++) {
   if (j*NUMPLOTS+i < bytes)
     printf ("%hd\t", su.shint[j*NUMPLOTS+i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Should be

```
for (i = 0; i < NUMPLOTS; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < DATAPERROW; j++) {
    if (i*DATAPERROW+j < bytes)
      printf ("%hd\t", su.shint[i*DATAPERROW+j]);
    }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain to me how that fix what I had?

Comment: Sure. What we want to achieve, is the same thing when you read. You grab the first line (in this case number 0), and go through it. After that, we do the same with the second line.
So, here the inner loop goes through a line, but we need the index to start from the beginning of the line. This is the i*DATAPERROW number.
The outer loop loops through the lines, so that's why it goes outside.
I hope it is clear this way, but if you have further question, feel free to ask.

Comment: How does +j come into play in this situation if all the data are contained in i*DATAPERROW?

Comment: Because this way you print by byte, and you have to go through the line. If you see the value of "i*DATAPERROW+j" it is 0, then 1, then 2, 3, 4 ... SIZE. You could write this way too:  
  
    for(int i=0;i<bytes;i++){  
      printf("%hd\t",su,shint[i]);
      if(i%DATAPERROW==0)
         printf("\n");
    }